# How do I tell my app to read exactly what the string contains?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, contains

Stumbled on an issue I can't seem to figure out. I have an app that spits out a certain amount of points depending what the string is so if someone says "not 1" then my app will show -4 points for number 1. If someone says "its 2" then the app will award 12 points for 2. 
So now my issue is, If someone says "its 2" and awards 12 points which is great, exactly what I want. But when someone says "its not 2" it still awards 12 points to 2 because it contains the word "its", when I want it to show -4 points.

```
|| vote.lowercased().contains("its")
|| vote.lowercased().contains("its not")
```

I want it to be able to see if it contains exactly "its not" then it will know to -4 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to distinguish `its` and `its not` you have to check for the longer string first

```
if vote.lowercased().contains("its not") {
   // -4 points
} else if vote.lowercased().contains("its") {
   // 12 points
}
```

Comment: Haha, Oh wow why didn't I think of that!. Worked perfectly thanks!